# fixed/floating div element when scrolling

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, html

I'm trying to search for this on the web, but I'm not sure what to look for exactly. I'm trying to find out how to create a div element that will be fixed, or float ONLY when the TOP of the element reaches the TOP of the window browser view. For instance, if an element is half way of the page, when you continue to scroll down, that element will stay put UNTIL its about to disappear, then it would want to stay at the top of my browser (fixed).

Comment: do you need something like gmails floating tool bar???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think I'm doing something similar to what you want to do. Try out the following code, put whatever you need in notification div and leave the anchor one alone.

```
<div id="notification-anchor"></div>
<div id="notification"></div>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(function() {
        var a = function() {
            var b = $(window).scrollTop();
            var d = $("#notification-anchor").offset().top;
            var c = $("#notification");
            if (b > d) {
                c.css({position:"fixed",top:"0px"})
            } else {
                c.css({position:"absolute",top:""})
            }
        };
        $(window).scroll(a);a()
    });
</script>
```

Edit: You should note, this requires you to include JQuery if that's not obvious to you.

Comment: oh wow, yeah its working! Thanks! I was wondering, is there a way to make it more smooth? If you scroll fast, it will have a little jitter.

Comment: Ya, you get that jitter because when you scroll the image (or whatever it is) and it moves past the top it will display it for a split second before fixing it. You would have to write an event handler for the scroll which checks for that in order to get rid of it, but I'm not sure where to point you for that. There is a JQuery module out there called mousewheel that might help...

Comment: Thanks a bunch. But maybe if you time, you might be able to answer another question i have? Instead of $(window).scrollTop(), I have a header banner on top which is like 40px away from the top of my browser, how would I make it scroll when it hits the bottom of my div? Thanks a bunch!