# To move/fix a DIV element to top upon scrolling the page

Tags: javascript, css, html

Please find below a sample HTML code that fixes the position of a DIV element. Now, I need to be able to move the "setupBar" to (0, 0) position (or appropriate position based on where the scroll position is) once I start scrolling, and then just freeze it.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=us-ascii">
</head>
<body>
<div id="mainBar" style="height:20px; border:1px solid red"></div>
<div id="setupBar" style="position:fixed; border:1px solid blue; height:20px; width:100%"></div>
<div style="height:1500px; background-color:#CCCCCC"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

PS: I am looking for a JS solution that can move the DIV up or down depending on the current scroll position (not a CSS fix) :)

Comment: I am curious why you wouldn't just want to use a position:fixed; css style definition to do this? It seems like a cleaner solution than a js one.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7735002/681807

Comment: CSS is better for this purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, You want this  http://jsfiddle.net/Kr4TJ/4/

I set `setupBar` position to `absolute` to make it naturally fallow `mainBar` when document scrolled. When `mainBar` is not visible anymore, the position of `setupBar` is set to `fixed` and `top` distance set to `0px`. If `mainBar` is visible again, then `setupBar` position change back to `absolute` and set `style.top=""` which brings back to natural position.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=us-ascii">
<script type="text/javascript">
function $(obj)
{
    return document.getElementById(obj);
}
function fixSetupBar()
{
    $("setupBar").style.top=(document.body.scrollTop)+"px";
    $("setupBar").style.left=(document.body.scrollLeft)+"px";
}
</script>
</head>
<body onscroll="fixSetupBar()">
<div id="mainBar" style="height:20px; border:1px solid red"></div>
<div id="setupBar" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;border:1px solid blue; height:20px; width:100%"></div>
<div style="height:1500px; background-color:#CCCCCC"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps.